# Chrome extension with movable/resizable popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome browser extension with a resizable and movable popup window. I'm after a similar UX to a popup window launched with `action.default_popup`, but with support for moving and resizing the popup.

I've tried switching to launching a popup using:

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: 'index.html',
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    type: 'popup',
    focused: true,
  });
});
```

However:

1. When Chrome is in fullscreen mode, the width and height of the popup is ignored and launches as a fullscreen window
2. Secondary issue: when launched without fullscreen mode, the popup window has a title bar (it would be great if it could be the same as `default_popup`)
   [image: popup window with title bar]

I think `type: 'panel'` is what I want, however, using `panel` behaves like `popup` and the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#type-CreateType) says that `panel` is deprecated:

> 'panel' is deprecated and is available only to existing whitelisted extensions on Chrome OS.

Is it possible to launch a popup window as a *panel* with an initial size even if Chrome is in fullscreen mode? And, is it possible to open a popup window *frameless* (i.e. without the title bar)

Comment: No, but you can add it to the web page as an iframe element. It can be draggable/resizable too. The only downsize is that a site can delete it.